# Why Login page doesn't reset state when navigating to Home page?

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation, react-native-state

I am using react-navigation and when a user logs in, it redirects to Home screen. However, when I go back to Login, I can see the state is not reset. Basically, it is keeping state the same as I left when navigating to Home.

```
this.state = {
   loading: false
};
```

Case explanation : **when log in clicked, set `loading` to true and go to `home` screen. In `Home` screen click `Back` which redirects to `Login`, where `loading` is still set to True.**

That seems odd, never experienced that. I thought react sets state on load.

Comment: If you are using react-navigation stack then this is correct behaviour. It will mount the component once in the stack. You can try workaround ie focus event to reset the screen or use redux state.

Comment: @SaachiTech thanks, I am now using reset but that's strange. There are so many screens so I am not sure when and where should I use it. Or do I have to reset state before I move to another screen?

Comment: I would suggest to use focus event. Read more about it here https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-events/